# using <g:select remoteFunction> grails

Tags: ajax, grails, gsp, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I have general question regarding using  remoteFunction. I am using the  like

i am making call to controller. I want to update a textbox based on the object from controller.

```
<g:fieldValue bean="${ProfileDomainInstance}" field="profileDescription" id="profileDescription"/>
```

how can i return profileDoaminInstance object from controller so that i can use that in my GSP.profilenames are comin from different object . I tried to send it as regular model.

```
def getProfileDescription(){
        println("came here")
        println(params?.profileName)
.
.
.
        [ProfileDomainInstance:ProfileDomainInstance])
    }
```

how can i send this object to gsp. I also tried to render the view. It was still not working.

Comment: I think there was some part missing.... I am using the <g:select>as:

Comment: <g:select  from='${ProfileList?.profileName}' name= 'ProfileSelect' id='ProfileSelect' noSelection="['null':' SELECT Profile']" disabled="true" onChange="${remoteFunction(action:'getProfileDescription',
                       params: '\'profileName=\' + this.value',update:[success:'profileDescription'])}"  />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create template for your profileDescription and use [render](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/render.html) on your controller  to render it

so your code will be something like this

```
def getProfileDescription(){
        println("came here")
        println(params?.profileName)
.
.
.
render(template:"/profileDescriptionTemplate", model:[ProfileDomainInstance:ProfileDomainInstance ] )

       )


<div id='divForprofileDescription'>
<g:render template="profileDescriptionTemplate" model="['ProfileDomainInstance':ProfileDomainInstance]" /> 
</div>


<g:select from='${ProfileList?.profileName}' name= 'ProfileSelect' id='ProfileSelect' noSelection="['null':' SELECT Profile']" disabled="true" onChange="${remoteFunction(action:'getProfileDescription', params: '\'profileName=\' + this.value',update:[success:'divForprofileDescription'])}
    }
```